# Terrible undergraduate transcripts. Everything else is good. Is it still worth applying to a Ph.D program in economics in a top 30 U.S. university?

Tags: phd, application, economics

I am an international student who is thinking of applying to a Ph.D program in economics at some top 30 economics departments in the U.S. I have a bachelor's and a master's degree in economics. My GRE, both verbal and quant, puts me well above the 90th percentile. My TOEFL is very high. I have three outstanding recommendations, probably placing me at the top of my master's class and comparing me favorably with former coleagues that were accepted to top universities. My master's disertation will make for a very good writing sample (the paper that grew out of it is serious research, publishable in the best theory journals) and I have two years' work experience at a prestigious job at the public sector. My master's transcripts are almost impeccable, even though I completed a LOT more coursework than what was required to graduate. I have plenty of maths coursework under my belt.

The only "small" wrinkle is: I was the archetype of a wayward student as an undergrad. My undergraduate transcripts are a disaster, as in I flunked 12 of the 70 courses that I enrolled in, simply because I had the terrible habit of abandoning classes when there was something more interesting going on. What I want to know is if this problem destroys my chances of acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, your more recent work will matter far more than your past work.  You'll see this as a common theme in the many answers already on Academia SE that relate to this subject.

However, as someone who has been through the economics PhD application process, and knows quite a bit about it, I think you need to temper your "top 30" program cutoff.  To get into top-30 programs you'll often be competing against students who did as well as you in later work, got perfect scores on the GRE quant, AND didn't have problems in past work.

If your math, at a *bare minimum* covers differential calculus and real analysis, then given the other things you've said I think you might stand a chance at top-30 programs, especially if your private sector job involved any research with your name on it, even if its just an acknowledgment.  So yes, it's worth applying, but I wouldn't suggest setting your *expectations* on that range.

Comment: Yes, my maths courses cover real analysis, analysis on metric spaces, multivariate calculus, linear algebra, linear and nonlinear programming,  complex variables, probability and measure theory, stochastic processes and more. The less advanced subjects I took during my undergrad years though, so my grades are less than stellar. Additionally, I have a paper in the process of submission, but that already received great feedback from professors at top departments. Thanks for the answer, it has helped me a whole deal. Sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is: How much does it cost you to apply? Some time to put together an application and some generally-modest application fees. Why not try and see what happens? If you get accepted, celebrate. If not, you gave it your best try.

If your real question is, What are the chances that I will be accepted?, answering that would depend on knowing a lot more detail about what you've done since you "straightened up". (Not saying I could evaluate it if I knew all the details -- I've never been an admissions officer at any college -- but others could.)

Comment: The problem is, due to current exchange rates, fees are not all that modest. Also, there's the opportunity cost of giving up my job to consider, but that's a no-brainer if I'm admitted at top 30 departments.

Comment: @someguy I don't see why you'd have to give up your job just because you applied but were not accepted. The question of whether you should give up your job to further your education only comes up if you're accepted, which is a totally different question from the one under discussion.